# Application.Terminate doesn't

Tags: delphi

If I call Application.Terminate *OR* Application.MaiForm.Close inside a method. the application doesn't terminate!

```
procedure doSomething;
var
  ErrorFound: boolean;
begin
  [...]
  try
    if ErrorFound then
      Application.Terminate;
  finally
  [...]
  end;
end;
```

I cannot understand why.

Please note that I'm calling Application.Terminate from inside a Try...Finally block, in the Try section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely you are calling `Application.Terminate` from a busy loop that itself does not terminate. If you enter an event handler but never return from it then calling `Application.Terminate` or `Application.MainForm.Close` would indeed be futile. These routines that close an application are cooperative. They post messages to the main message loop requesting that the application gracefully shuts down.

For example, the following code would exhibit the symptoms you describe:

```
procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  while True do
    Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Another (more likely) possibility is that you are calling this function from inside a modal form but not closing the modal form.

Unless you show more code, we are reduced to making guesses like this.

Comment: Yes, Application.Terminate is inside a for loop and procedure DoSomething is called from inside a TAction's event handler. Anyway, how can one exit from an event handler like the one in your example?

Comment: Call the exit function to leave the current function but you may need to exit higher up the chain. Abort is another option.

Comment: Perhaps if you post the calling routine we can answer that for you.

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer, also for your space removal question from yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by David Heffernan's answer above, (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8078808/1041047), I added a line of code after TApplication.Terminate:

```
Application.Terminate;

Application.ProcessMessages;
```

and it works.